# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound' what to do?

Tags: python

I've been editing this mp3 player, but this error keeps apearing

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import playsound

#making the window
window = Tk()
window.title("button")
window.geometry("350x450+500+200")

#making the song fuction
def song():
    playsound ("lights.mp3")

# making texbox
def InitialMessage():
    name = name_Tf.get()
    mood = mood_Tf.get()
    
    #mood happy
    if mood == "happy":
        return messagebox.showinfo("message", 
                                    f"""Hi! {name}, wellcome. 
    may I intrest you with some music?""",
         #making the song executer
         button1 = Button(messagebox,
                        text="yes",
                        command=song,
                        font= ("Comic Sans", 15 )))
```

I don't have python 2 on the pc anymore, I uninstalled it, I have tried reinstaling playsound, as well as change the interpreter to the recomended, I dunno what to do anymore, please help

Comment: Which command do you type in order to run the script?

Comment: ...and how did you install playsound? Which commands? And are you using a virtual environment? Because the same Python you use to install playsound should be the same Python you use to run your app.

Comment: I'm using the comand prompt of windows for both

Answer (score 0):

Try importing playsound with PIP

> pip install playsound

And include in your code

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/path/to/a/sound/file/you/want/to/play.mp3')
```